# Can I serialize an ArrayList without serializing objects which holds?

Tags: java, json, serialization, collections, gson

Some of objects in my code appear in more than one lists/maps. E.G: the object Question myQuestion is in both ArrayList java and ArrayList serialization. And as far as I know, Gson serializes objects in an ArrayList along with the ArrayList itself. To test it, I ran the following code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class serTries {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Player> players=new ArrayList<>();
    List<Player> secondaryPlayer =new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
        players.add(i, new Player("John " + i));
        secondaryPlayer.add(players.get(i));
    } //creating 3 Player objects and putting them in 2 different lists.

        try {
                Gson gson = new Gson();
            String ser=gson.toJson(players);
            String secondarySer=gson.toJson(secondaryPlayer);
            Type ct = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Player>>(){}.getType();
                    System.out.println("First list:\n" + ser + "\nSecond list:\n" + secondarySer);
}catch( Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
} } }
```

It produces the following:

> First list:
>   [{"name":"John 0"},{"name":"John 1"},{"name":"John 2"}]
>   Second list:
>   [{"name":"John 0"},{"name":"John 1"},{"name":"John 2"}]

and when I create a new list by typing

```
List<Player> deserializedPlayers = gson.fromJson(ser, ct);  
List<Player> deserializedSecondaryPlayers = gson.fromJson(secondarySer, ct);
```

It creates 6 different objects (3 players from first, and 3 from the second list.)

My question is, is there any way to make it so I can serialize/deserialize a List called onlinePlayers which refers to an instance of "John 1", which also happens to be in List allPlayers, without duplicating "John 1" while still refering to that object?
I'm guessing when I deserialize allPlayers, it will create objects which are different than original ones, so there is no way onlinePlayers can still refer to same object after deserialization. Should I write a custom method to add newly created instance of "John 1" to onlinePlayers after deserialization?

Thank you

Comment: What does *"ArrayList java and ArrayList serialization"* mean?

Comment: Sounds like you need [Custom Deserialization](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I serialize an ArrayList without serializing objects which holds?

Short answer.  No.

The point of serialization is that you can reconstruct a copy of the original object from the serialization.  If you don't include a serialization of the list elements, then you won't be able to reconstruct the list.

I think you need change the type of the list you are trying to serialize to be a list of names, not a list of players.  Alternatively, consider using a database rather than "dumb" serialization.

---

> My question is, is there any way to make it so I can **deserialize** a List called onlinePlayers which refers to an instance of "John 1", which also happens to be in List allPlayers, without duplicating "John 1" while still refering to that object?

If you were using Java Object Serialization, you could implement a `readResolve` method on the `Player` object that looked up the object being deserialized and compared it against a "global" in-memory data structure.  (But this is conceptually wrong on a number of levels.)

You could do something similar with a GSON custom deserializer.  Alternatively, you could use an event-based JSON reader and use the events to extract the information you needed.

But I think this is the wrong approach.

---

Here's the nub of the problem.

> However, I thought extracting a data from players list (which holds thousands of objects) ...

Serialization / deserialization is the wrong solution for this if you have thousands of objects:

- To update you need to serialize / write the *entire* list and all objects it contains.  Each time.  Even if you only made a small change.
- To read, you need to do *most* of the work of deserializing, even with your proposed "hack".
- There is no easy / quick way to do queries against the serialized form.
- At some point you need to hold the *entire* deserialized object graph in memory.  This does not scale.

You should use a database of some kind.

Comment: Title is misleading. The actual question is about deserialization, not serialization. The question essentially is: *When deserializing `{"name":"John 1"}` the second time, it currently creates a new `Player` object. Can it be changed to use the existing `Player[name=John 1]` object from the first deserialization?* See paragraph starting "My question is...". Hate it when title is out-of-sync with actual question.

Comment: That's what I thought as an alternative solution. However, I thought extracting a data from players list (which holds thousands of objects) each time someone checks online players would be pointless performance wise. As an example, if there's an option that allows people to see locations of players when they look at online players, code would have to find corresponding players from allPlayers list and check their  .location field. So I thought directly putting that player object in onlinePlayers would be much better. I guess I will have to think some more, clearly I'm on the wrong track.

Comment: If you have a player list with 1000 players you should not be using serialization.  Use a database.

Comment: @Stephen I don't know where to start from. Could you point me in the right direction? Don't I still need to serialize objects in order to put them in a database anyway?

Comment: No you don't need to serialize objects to put them into a database.  You could start with reading this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/.  Choosing an appropriate database will be another issues ...